# cloudfoundry: Deploy a single application from manifest.yml where several are defined

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a cloud foundry manifest file like so:

```
---
applications:
- name: foo.bar.baz
  memory: 64M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  path: ./client
- name: foo.bar.buzz
  memory: 500m
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  path: target/my-project-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

How can I tell cloud foundry to push just one of these applications?

Answer (score 1):

Blast it... just read the docs again and all you need to do is run `cf push <app-name>` and cloud foundry will push the app defined under that name in `manifest.yml`.